# Elixir behavior when guards fail in case expressions

Tags: erlang, elixir

Why does `case` not throw a runtime exception when a guard fails, and instead, fails silently thus hiding a potential bug?

For example why

```
case [] do
   xs when hd(xs) -> "Won't match"
   xs -> "Got #{xs}"
end
```

does not return an argument error due to the failure of `hd(xs)` ?

**UPDATE**: I made this question because the same situation does not happen with guards in Haskell. For example, the function

```
myfun x
  | head([]) == x = 100
  | otherwise = 200
```

when called in GHCi produces

```
λ> myfun 6
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

In short, in contrast to Haskell, which does not hide the exception to the programmer, what is the design rationale behind Elixir's behavior to eat the exception in the guard?

Thanks,

Comment: Because it’s how guards work. If it raised, this case would never be acting as a case. Use direct pattern match if you want an exception raised.

Comment: @mudasobwa What do you mean by acting as a `case`? To me something that masquerades bugs in a program is a design flaw in the language.

Comment: According to your logic, all languages allowing rescuing exceptions have a design flow. It does not masquerade anything. It explicitly catches any possible exceptions and returns `false`. This allows being more succinct in guards, which is perfect. This a _guard_, not a random piece of code. The fact that it seems as a design flow _to you_, has nothing to do with the design flow _exists_ in reality.

Comment: @mudasobwa No, no, this is not an explicit catch, it is an implicit one. Do you not consider a bug if your program outside of a guard accesses the head of an empty list and the language throws you a runtime exception for that as Elixir does? Or do you prefer to get a nil in that case and move on? If Elixir throws an exception outside of a guard, its behavior inside guards should have been made consistent with this.

Comment: _“the behavior inside guards should have been made consistent with this”_ — oh really? Why is that? Because you are unfamiliar with `guards`? Catch by `guard` is **an explicit catch**, as clearly said everywhere in the documentation. This is a contract: `rescue` and `guard` are both _the explicit catch_. Live with that :)

Comment: @mudasobwa You did not answer any of my questions, and seem to really like Elixir very much ... :)

Comment: The fact that you did not understand answers does not make me not answering the questions. You have invented some must-be rules, having nothing to do with common sense and keep asking why the world differs from what you think is correct. The answer is “it is done that way.” It is convenient and proven by 30+ years of experience. Feel free to write your own language that behaves differently.

Comment: @mudasobwa Take the red pill and learn Elm or Haskell, and enlighten your mind with them. Cheers.

Comment: I do not need to “learn Elm or Haskell,” I have an experience with both and I professionally work with `Idris` and I must admit strong typing sucks. That simple. It’s a dead end. Academical approaches give a birth to developers who are brave to blame anything for being not as slim as dreamed, but it does not live in the business environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160096/discussion-between-mljrg-and-mudasobwa).

Answer (score 3):

Any errors raised by guard functions are silently ignored and the match is considered unsuccessful. This is documented at http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id84741:

> If an arithmetic expression, a Boolean expression, a short-circuit expression, or a call to a guard BIF fails (because of invalid arguments), the entire guard fails. If the guard was part of a guard sequence, the next guard in the sequence (that is, the guard following the next semicolon) is evaluated.

Comment: My question was not how it works, but why it works that way. It seems a design flaw to me giving programmers the opportunity to have their bugs silently ignored. Is there any strong reason for this behavior in the language?